# python scrapy xpath:InternalError: (1136, u"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

There is My Code.When I crawl other url,it's no problem,but when I crawl this url.it ask me the column doesn't match.I don't know why count length is Character length，not the dict length?

```
class JikespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "jikespider"
  allowed_domains = ["fromgeek.com"]
  start_urls = ['http://www.fromgeek.com/topic/']

  def parse(self, response):
     sel = Selector(response)
     jike_list = sel.xpath('//ul[@id="masonry0"]')
     ll = len(sel.xpath('//ul[@id="masonry0"]/li'))
     for jike in range(ll):
        item = JikeItem()
        try:
            item['jike_title'] = jike_list.xpath('//li/div/div[@class="n-pic fl"]/a/@title').extract()[jike].strip()
            item['jike_uptime'] = jike_list.xpath('//li/div/div[@class="n-keytime "]/div[@class="time fr"]/text()').extract()[jike].strip()
            item['jike_tag'] = jike_list.xpath('//li/div/div[@class="n-keytime "]/div[@class="key fl"]').xpath('string(.)').extract()[jike].strip()
            print len(item['jike_title'])
            print len(item['jike_uptime'])
            print len(item['jike_tag'])
            print '--------------------------'
            yield item
        except Exception,e:  
            print e
```

Comment: Please show your `items.py` and if you store the scraped items into `db` then `pipeline` code too, since the items are scraped but issue occurs during processing the item obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your error message with the code. (`scrapy 1.3.2`, `Python 2.7.11`).

And i'm wondering why you don't loop over the `selector list` but build a counter do access the elements. With nested XPath queries it's much easier.

```py
class JikespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jikespider"
    allowed_domains = ["fromgeek.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.fromgeek.com/topic/']

    def parse(self, response):

        sel_jike_list = response.xpath('//ul[@id="masonry0"]/li')
        for sel_jike in sel_jike_list:
            item = JikeItem()
            item['jike_title'] = sel_jike.xpath('.//div[@class="n-pic fl"]/a/@title').extract_first()
            # ... other fields
            yield item
```

Please note the dot at the beginning of the nested XPath.